# Winforms custom loading screen text not loading

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using VB.NET winforms and have a particular form that take a while to load up so I've decided to implement a loading screen to make it feel a bit less freezey. Here is the code I'm using in my freezey form load.

```
Private Sub HanleyView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim loaderForm As New Loader
    loaderForm.Show()
    AllOpenOrdersList.FullRowSelect = True
    NeedsAttentionList.FullRowSelect = True
    StockManagementList.FullRowSelect = True
    Dim lowStockCount = HelperMethods.ReviewLowStock()
    ReviewLowStockButton.Text = "Review Low Stock (" & lowStockCount & ")"
    RefreshAllOpenOrdersList()
    RefreshNeedsAttentionList()
    RefreshStockManagementList()
    loaderForm.Close()
End Sub
```

So I start by showing the loading form and finish by closing it.

The good new is that the loading form appears, but the bad news is the "LOADING..." text which is a label on my loading form doesn't show, I just get a white patch there instead. I've tried two approaches, the above and calling Loader.Show and Loader.Close. I've also tried setting loaderForm.Label1.Text = "LOADING..." but this didn't make any difference. Each time the form loads (and the title loads which says "Loading please wait") but not the label on the form itself.

I've now also tried:

```
    Dim loaderForm As New Loader
    Dim lbl As New Label
    loaderForm.Controls.Add(lbl)
    lbl.Text = "LOADING..."
    lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(42, 21)
    loaderForm.Show()
    AllOpenOrdersList.FullRowSelect = True
    NeedsAttentionList.FullRowSelect = True
    StockManagementList.FullRowSelect = True
    Dim lowStockCount = HelperMethods.ReviewLowStock()
    ReviewLowStockButton.Text = "Review Low Stock (" & lowStockCount & ")"
    RefreshAllOpenOrdersList()
    RefreshNeedsAttentionList()
    RefreshStockManagementList()
    loaderForm.Close()
```

But this hasn't worked either.

**EDIT: I've tried Varocarbas' code but was still unsuccessful. The form loads but the text remains a white patch**

```
    Dim loaderForm As Form = New Form
    With loaderForm
        .Height = 200
        .Width = 300
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
    End With

    Dim label1 As Label = New Label
    loaderForm.Controls.Add(label1)

    With label1
        .Text = "LOADING..."
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 45)
    End With

    loaderForm.Show()
```

[image: No Loading text Showing]

**EDIT 2: For clarity, here is my code now it is working using Franck suggestion**

```
Private Sub HanleyView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim loaderForm As New Loader
    loaderForm.Show()
    Application.DoEvents()
    AllOpenOrdersList.FullRowSelect = True
    NeedsAttentionList.FullRowSelect = True
    StockManagementList.FullRowSelect = True
    Dim lowStockCount = HelperMethods.ReviewLowStock()
    ReviewLowStockButton.Text = "Review Low Stock (" & lowStockCount & ")"
    RefreshAllOpenOrdersList()
    RefreshNeedsAttentionList()
    RefreshStockManagementList()
    loaderForm.Close()
End Sub
```

I have kept my original code and simply added Application.DoEvents() below loaderform.Show and it works properly now.

Also the below screenshot is what I mean by using the designer (and not doing it programmtically):

[image: Loader Form Designer View]

Comment: Is ReviewLowStock doing lots of stuff on the UI thread?

Comment: Not much compared to the three Refresh method just before loaderForm.Close()

Comment: There's your problem then. See the answer about multi-threading below

Comment: the whole form doesn't seems to call all the `OnPaint` events of the controls because your code is in a single thread which will hang everything. it make sense. Anyhow as quick fix you can just call `Application.DoEvent` in the form load and right after the `.Show()`. I said quick fix but i highly suggest you search for threading such as background worker so the loading fomr don't get frozen

Comment: Thank you Franck. This worked a charm. Threading is definitely on my to do list as this is the second time I've run into a problem that could be solved with threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multithreading!

Create and run the `loaderForm` on a separate thread. But then you need to be careful about cross-thread operations, so have a self-invoking method on your `loaderForm`, such as:

```
Public Sub ParseStatus(msg as String)
     If Me.InvokeRequired Then Me.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf Me.ParseStatus), msg) Else Me.Label1.Text = msg
End Sub
```

Also in your `loaderForm` you want something like:

```
Public Sub Finish()
      Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
      Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Then in the `Load` procedure of your form:

```
Private Sub HanleyView_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim loaderForm As New Loader
    Dim loaderThread As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf loaderForm.ShowDialog))
    loaderThread.Start()

    loaderForm.ParseStatus("Loading ...")

    AllOpenOrdersList.FullRowSelect = True
    NeedsAttentionList.FullRowSelect = True
    StockManagementList.FullRowSelect = True
    Dim lowStockCount = HelperMethods.ReviewLowStock()
    ReviewLowStockButton.Text = "Review Low Stock (" & lowStockCount & ")"

    LoaderForm.ParseStatus("Refreshing open orders ...")
    RefreshAllOpenOrdersList()

    loaderForm.ParseStatus("Refreshing needs attentions?") ' etc
    RefreshNeedsAttentionList()
    RefreshStockManagementList()

    loaderForm.Finish()
End Sub
```

But Visual Studio has a neat thing called `SplashScreen` in its project templates for VB.NET. I'd use that one, if you aren't already…

**Edit: I corrected the syntax errors in the code.**

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with the original problem of the OP; it might explain why he is not able to see the label now; when the original problem is solved and he is complaining about a new one ("why the label is not showing?"). He is executing lots of things from the Form Load event and this might be the reason (although needs to share more information).

Comment: In any case your code has quite a few problems (and not too many explanations).

Comment: I didn't say it's elegant or good by design... But my code provides a shortcut to get the Label to be displayed... you could call it a hack if you like.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I meant that your code does not even compile. But the idea is good (this might be the reason for the last OP's problem), I will add a multi-threading suggestion to my answer shortly.

Comment: But, as you can see, no big deal: your code does not compile (someone tells you that and you don't do anything about it), you don't answer the main question, etc. but keep getting +1s; anyway... I have added a PROPERLY-WORKING multi-threading code to my answer (which also addresses the original concern of the OP; this was his second problem). You should update your answer such that you code works fine (think in future readers); if you prefer to keep it more generically ("rely on multithreading and use the splash screen functionality, etc."), you should remove your code.

Comment: Right, now it does compile, providing the name of the loader form is 'Loader' it contains a Label by the name of Label1/
Also Threading does not have to be imported anymore.
And yes i removed the brackets in the AddressOf definition.

Comment: Yes, it compiles now; unfortunately, it does not work. Please, execute this code under the conditions you propose and see what happens. (it is kind of funny: I participated in another question about recursive definition of classes a while ago)

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it, but mine works fine.
Could you be more specific as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: You cannot execute this code from the Class called Loader without triggering an error. Although the OP seems to have two forms and Loader being an external one, in that case it might work (didn't test it); but you were saying the contrary (calling this from inside Loader). Anyway... really long discussion with a pretty non-sensible person (the OP) what is really tiring to me and now not feeling like re-testing this. If it works, everything is OK.